# Quorum migration to the latest version

Tags: migration, quorum

I have a Quorum network setup with an older version where constellation is being used. I am trying to migrate the whole network to the latest version of Quorum.

I successfully migrated the constellation data to mysql using the tessera migration script provided in git.

But I am facing a typical problem when I am trying to migrate the data from geth i.e. the leveldb part. I copied the chaindata and lightchaindata folder from the old datadir/geth to new datadir/geth.

Now when I am trying to start the geth it is throwing an error stating that chainid cannot be used as 1, unfortunately  the chainid of my existing network, which I want to migrate, is 1. I analysed the source code of the latest version of Quorum and found an explicit exception is thrown if the chainid is set as 1.

May you please help me  to find a solution for this.

**Still unanswered**

I think the manual migration is the only option here.

Thanks,
Shamik.